# How to call prepared statements in java properly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a prepared statement in my database called BalanceOnDate and when I tried to call it from following method I get following error, I tried hard to figure it out but I don't see any clue for the solution please assist me,

```
public void fillClosingMontBalance(Month closingMonth) throws Exception {
        Connection con = connection;
        CallableStatement csForPreMonth = (CallableStatement) connection.prepareCall("{call BalanceOnDate(?,?,?)}");

        for (Iterator i = ledgerList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Ledger ledger = (Ledger) i.next();
            csForPreMonth.setString(1, "St_" + ledger.getStockType());
            csForPreMonth.setString(2, ledger.getFullLedgerNo());
            csForPreMonth.setString(3, closingMonth.getFullDate());
            ResultSet curRs = csForPreMonth.executeQuery();
            curRs.last();

            MonthEndBalance endBalance = new MonthEndBalance(curRs.getString("itmTyp"), curRs.getString("fulItmCode"),
                    curRs.getDouble("op_Balance"), curRs.getDouble("balance"), curRs.getDouble("total_received"),
                    curRs.getDouble("total_issued"), curRs.getString("unit"), curRs.getString("batchNo"),
                    curRs.getDouble("rawPrice"), curRs.getDouble("avg_unit_price"), curRs.getDate("sysDateTime"),
                    curRs.getString("facCode"), curRs.getString("comCode"), curRs.getString("fullLedgerNo"),
                    curRs.getString("stockType"), curRs.getString("fullItemName"));
            closingMonthRecords.add(endBalance);
        }
    }
```

Error;

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION BalanceOnDate does not exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2690)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1465)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getCallStmtParameterTypes(DatabaseMetaData.java:1602)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureOrFunctionColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:4141)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:4059)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.determineParameterTypes(CallableStatement.java:830)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.<init>(CallableStatement.java:628)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4CallableStatement.<init>(JDBC4CallableStatement.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.getInstance(CallableStatement.java:524)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.parseCallableStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4081)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:4165)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:4139)
        at Manufacturing.MonthEnd.FinishMonth.fillPreviousMonthBalanceRec(FinishMonth.java:69)
        at COMMON.FrmMDI.jButton4ActionPerformed(FrmMDI.java:4117)
        at COMMON.FrmMDI.access$14300(FrmMDI.java:72)
        at COMMON.FrmMDI$96.actionPerformed(FrmMDI.java:1678)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:253)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6203)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5968)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4564)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4390)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4461)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4125)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4055)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2149)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4390)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:649)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:622)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:620)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:619)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

following is my stored procedure in the database,

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`user1`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BalanceOnDate`(stname varchar(20),ledno varchar(100), fDate Varchar(12))
BEGIN
set @x = concat('
SELECT 
Ledger.`StockType` AS Ledger_StockType,
Ledger.`FullLedgerNo` AS Ledger_FullLedgerNo,
Ledger.`BackLedgerNo` AS Ledger_BackLedgerNo,
Ledger.`ForwdLedgerNo` AS Ledger_ForwdLedgerNo,
Ledger.`OpeningBalance`AS Ledger_OpeningBalance,
Ledger.`ClosingBalance`AS Ledger_ClosingBalance,
Ledger.`Unit` AS Ledger_Unit,
Ledger.`User` AS Ledger_User,
Ledger.`ItemType` AS Ledger_ItemType,
Ledger.`Active` AS Ledger_Active,
Ledger.`FullITCode` AS Ledger_FullITCode,
St.`ID` AS St_BFG_ID,
St.`InQty` AS St_BFG_InQty,
St.`OutQty` AS St_BFG_OutQty,
round(St.InQ - St.OuQ, 2) as Balance,
St.`Remarks` AS St_BFG_Remarks,
St.`BatchNo` AS St_BFG_BatchNo,
St.`EventNo` AS St_BFG_EventNo,
St.`FrToLedgerNo` AS St_BFG_FrToLedgerNo,
St.`FrmEvent` AS St_BFG_FrmEvent,
St.`User` AS St_BFG_User,
St.`Dat` AS St_BFG_Dat,
St.`Unit` AS St_BFG_Unit,
St.`RawPrice` as St_row_price,
St.`Uprice` as UnitPrice,
St.`Balance` as St_balance,
item_grade.`FulItmName` AS item_grade_FulItmName,
Company.`CompanyName` AS Company_CompanyName,
Factory.`Factory` AS Factory_Factory,
St.`SupID` AS St_BFG_SupID 
FROM (SELECT @inCsum:=0,@outCsum:=0) as xyz,
(SELECT @inCsum := @inCsum + InQty as InQ,@outCsum := @outCsum + OutQty as OuQ,d.*
FROM ',stname,' d WHERE FullLedgerNo= "',ledno,'" and Dat <= "', fDate ,'" ORDER BY Dat, SupID) as St
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Ledger` as Ledger ON St.`FullLedgerNo` = Ledger.`FullLedgerNo`     
LEFT OUTER JOIN `item_grade` item_grade ON Ledger.`FullITCode` = item_grade.`FulItmCode`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Factory` Factory ON St.`FacCode` = Factory.`FacCode` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Company` Company ON Ledger.`ComCode` = Company.`ComCode` 
WHERE  Ledger.`FullLedgerNo` = "',ledno,'" and St.`Unit` = Ledger.`Unit`');
PREPARE stmt FROM @x;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: What part of `FUNCTION BalanceOnDate does not exist` isn't clear?  It's telling you the stored procedure in the database called `BalanceOnDate` is not defined.  Either it doesn't exist or is in a different schema and the name needs to be qualified with the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the user account passed when creating the connection has been granted execute privileges on `BalanceOnDate`.